# Django: overriding single model field validation

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am using django.db.models.fields.DecimalField in one case, but its validation error is quite BAD.

like, when user enters 3,4 instead of 3.4 it says - 'Enter a number'. Well 3,4 is as much as number in some countries as 3.4 is. At least to those who perhaps are not well versed in computer stuff.

So for that reason i am trying to override this fields validation so i could validate it myself.

My problem is - before modelforms clean_my_field() is called, models own validation works and it already raises an error.

So i looked up https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects

After reading this i understood that i could do

```
def full_clean(self):
    super(MyModel, self).full_clean(exclude = 'my_field')
```

and my_field would be excluded from validation and i could validate it myself in

```
def clean(self)
    pass
    #how do i access cleaned data here anyway?
    #self.cleaned_data does not exist
    #is self.my_field the only way?
```

But alas - it does not work. self.my_field value is old value in clean() method and cleaned_data is nowhere to be found.

All this makes me think my approach is wrong. I could write my own field which extends django's DecimalField i guess. I thought this approach would work... Can someone clear this up for me as - WHY it does not work. why is that exclude there if it does not work? Django version 1.4.2 by the way.

Alan

Edit: I dug deeper. It seems that even if i override all models cleaning methods and dont use super in them at all - the fields are STILL cleaned at some point and the error is already raised by then.

I guess i will be doing some extending to django.db.models.fields.DecimalField in this case.

An answer about why the exclude is there in the full_clean method would still be nice. Why is it there if it does not work?

Comment: I went through a load of field validation code a while back and remember that there seemed to be a load of different methods for doing it. My guess is that `exclude` prevents one method from firing, but that's not the method that's being fired in your case. If you haven't already I'd suggest stepping through the source code to see what's happening. Good question anyway, +1 from me.

Comment: I just created my own version of DecimalField with its own validation and fixed my problems right there.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question but for the ones that didn't find an answer, what I did was to add localize=True in the ModelAdmin for the Admin Site:

```
formfield_overrides = {
    models.DecimalField: {'localize': True},
}
```

That will make the FormField locale aware, accepting comma as decimal separator (depending of the current locale, of course). It will also display it localized.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/formatting/#locale-aware-input-in-forms

If you are targeting a single DecimalField or you are writing a custom Form or ModelForm just follow the instructions on the URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
def views_name(request):
    ......
    field = dec_num(form.cleaned-data['....'])
    .........

    return render(request, 'page.html', {.....})


def dec_num(value):
    return value.replace(",",".")
```

Comment: This could perhaps even almost work. Probably not the way you write but something like dict = request.POST.copy(). then check the value like you do with dec_num(). And then pass dict to form instead of request.POST. But view sounds like a bad place for form/field validation